# **Visual Studio 2015, should I commit Project.sln.ide\* files into git?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015 CTP and it is generating a new folder named `<project>.sln.ide\` with a few files in it such as:

```
edb.chk
edb.log
edbres00001.jrs
edbres00002.jrs
edbtmp.log
storage.ide
```

Should I add these files (or the entire folder) into my `.gitignore`?

If it should be added into `.gitignore` what would be the proper syntax? I guess `*.sln.ide\` would be good?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should exclude the "*.ide" folder(s).

From [Microsoft](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/06/03/announcing-web-features-in-visual-studio-14-ctp.aspx):
"It also contains a “.sln.ide” folder which is used by Roslyn Compiler engine to store temporary files. This folder should be excluded from the source control system normally."

The "default" .gitignore for Visual Studio found on GitHub includes an exclusion for "*.ide", as seen [here](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore#L26).

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link to the default .gitignore in github.. I have not updated mine for a year.

Comment: it looks like the default .gitignore no longer includes .ide as an exclusion

Answer (score 4):

Any files that the other collaborators don't need to have in their environment to compile the source code should be placed into the `.gitignore` file.  If you're certain that the other collaborators are using the same IDE as yours, you should place that entire folder there.

The expression `**.ide/` works to block that directory.

Now, if you're not sure if everyone is going to use the same IDE, you can place the same expression inside of `.git/info/exclude`, which will create an exclusion entry exclusively for you on this project.